# Setting ControlSource on textbox in report

Tags: vba, report, ms-access-2010

In my report why is it that when I set the ControlSource on a textbox in a report to a field name like this: txtSomeTextBox.ControlSource = [Expr1] it populates as expected but when I define a user defined function like this:

```
Public Function GetString(strValues As String) As String
GetString = "Values: " & strValues
End Function
```

Then set the ControlSource property to txtSomeTextBox.ControlSource = GetString([Expr1]) it doesn't know what to do! In fact the textbox displays: "#Type!"  Why can't I pass the value of [Expr1] to the function?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `=` to evaluate a function.

`=GetString([Expr1])` as controlsource works for me.

Comment: I'm thinking that [Expr1] is not a String but some other data type?

Comment: @Alan: Then try `Public Function GetString(varValues As Variant) As String`

Comment: Tried it.  I get run time error: You entered an expression that has no value.

Comment: I found the problem.  The name of the textbox had a circurlar reference to itself.  Its name was the same as the field name.  I renamed the textbox to txtAllValues and that fix it.